# Angular Testing, are there better ways to write this code?

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular testing, but can't seem to find any good resources on if I'm doing this the proper way.

In my spec file, I am running a function `setDashboardGreeting(hours)` but this does the same thing as the function as I already have in my component: `getTime()`. Is there a way I can use the same function so I don't have to re-write it in my test?

```
describe('TestComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let dashboardGreeting;
  let hours;
  function setDashboardGreeting() {
    if (hours < 5) component.dashboardGreeting = 'Morning';
    else if (hours < 10) component.dashboardGreeting = 'Afternoon';
    else component.dashboardGreeting = 'Evening';
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    dashboardGreeting = '';
    component = new TestComponent();
  });

  describe('DashboardGreeting', () => {
    it('should return Morning', () => {
      let hours = 10
      setDashboardGreeting();

      expect(component.dashboardGreeting).toBe('Good Morning');
    });
  });
});
```

And then in my component, I have this function:

```
getTime() {
  const now = new Date();
  const hours = now.getHours();

  if (hours < 5) this.dashboardGreeting = 'Morning';
  else if (hours < 10) this.dashboardGreeting = 'Afternoon';
  else this.dashboardGreeting = 'Evening';
}
```

Do I need to re-write the if/else statement in my test or if this possible to use the `getTime()` function from my component?

Comment: Please share how exactly `getTime()` is executed by the component. Usually you would pass some sort of input or similar to the component, let the component itself update via `fixture.detectChanges()`, then test the results of the component updating such validating the text of a DOM element or checking that a different public property on the component has the correct value. Right now I'd say it's not an effective test as getTime() is not being called the by component.

Comment: This question is opinion based.  IMO, business logic belongs in services rather than in components.  I would personally move the getTime method over to a service and give it an optional Date parameter that defaults to new Date().  Then you could pass in a date and test the outputs.

Comment: – Alexander , the `getTime();` is being called via `ngOnInit() {`. My apologies for not including this on the original post, I was trying to keep in minimal. So onInit the getTime function is called which then sets the dashboardGreeting for the user.

Comment: I deleted the comment because after looking at `getTime()`, it looks like it just creates a new date, so does `hours` actually get passed? Or is it just derived from the current date time?

Comment: It is just derived from the current date time. Thanks for that, I got confused as well. So the `ngOnInit() {` calls the `getTime()`. This sets a new date and then gets the hours from the date. Using the hours, I determine what greeting I want to set whether that be morning, evening, or afternoon

Comment: For the most part i'm just interested if I can use this function ( `getTime()` ) in my test, or if I need to rewrite it in order to check different instances

Comment: I would not use `getTime()` in your test because date will be inconsistent given the component itself uses it's own date which would be different from the test. Usually with date/time you would use an API such as jamine [Clock](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/Clock.html) and set an explicit base date that both the test and component can use. Then you would test that the `component.dashboardGreeting` has the correct value. Angular testing documentation vaguely covers usage of jasmine.clock with fakeAsync as well https://angular.io/guide/testing#jasmineclock-with-fakeasync

Comment: It will be easier to test the three cases if you pass `getTime` a date or alternatively keep the date on the component as a public property.  Then you just test the outputs with a variety of dates.

Comment: Thank you both. I really appreciate it. May I ask, how did you learn Angular testing? Just by reading through the docs primarily accompanied with trial and error?

Comment: Thousands of hours of failure and doing it wrong =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to simplify the testing and reduce repetition would be to make it so that the date (`now` in your code) can be passed in by the unit tests.  For example:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  salutation = '';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.salutation = this.getSalutation(new Date());
  }

  getSalutation(date: Date): string {
    const hours = date.getHours();

    if (hours < 5)
      return 'Good Morning';
    else if (hours < 10)
      return 'Good Afternoon';
    else
      return 'Good Evening';
  }
}
```

Note that I renamed `getDate` to `getSalutation`.  I also made it return a value (`get`) rather than *set* a value.

From your tests you can then call `getSalutation` with a variety of dates to check that the salutations are as expected.  You can also check that `salutation` is set when `ngOnInit` is called, and that `ngOnInit` calls `getSalutation` with a `Date` instance using a spy.